# create UIIMageView in 3d with cubical shape

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cube, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to create a UIImageView having 4 sides with 4 different images,and if user swipes on visible interface of UIImageView i t should show next face of the cube with different image.
it Should allow left swipe and right swipe.
**final image should be like this.can any one suggest me code or any tutorial links to create like this.where should i star..?t**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could modify this to work:

https://github.com/augustjoki/CubeTabBarController

It has the animation code in it at least. You could start by altering it to use gestures to trigger the animation.